# Save just data after filter Pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

I've created pivot table with group and sub group. So I have 2 data sets in a row subtotal by one. Then I do filter(by value) to get Top 10 sub-groups with biggest value. I need to keep only top 10 data with no option to remove filter.

For example:

```html
Row 1: 

Shop name    Sales Value
Flower shop 1 
       
- red rose    500
- yellow rose    480
- ... to top 10
        
Flower shop 2

- black rose    520
- green rose    470
- ....
```

So I need to keep only top 10 in each shop with no possibility to see other flowers in each shop.
Copy-paste data as values is not an options because I don't get in desired format.

Answer (score 0):

I know the answer to this one now

assuming it's excel you are working with go to the file tab

then if for example it is excel 2010 you can  "Check for issues"

"inspect document"

then un tick everything except the "Hidden Rows and Columns" and "Hidden Worksheets"

then Inspect. once it has completed it will tell you how many hidden sections it has found and give you the option to delete. leaving you with only the filtered Data